# Rails: make (link_to "example", "#", remote: true) bypass (respond_to ... format.js)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-5

I have the following problem:

On my page I have 2 remote links. The first is:

```
<p><%= link_to "Description", "#", remote: true, id: "desc-link" %></p>
```

which is a simple link to fadeToggle the description of an object:

```
$(document).on "ready page:load", ->
  $("section.object").on "click", "#desc-link",  ->
    $("#object-desc").fadeToggle()
```

The second one is an Ajax call:

```
<a type="button" class="btn btn-default", 
  href='/users/<%= Object.find(object_to_display).user.id %>/objects',
  data-remote="true" id='object-link'>Test</a>
```

and the controller is supposed to do STUFF when it gets clicked:

```
def objects

  ...

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render "users/show_objects" }
    format.js { STUFF }
  end
end
```

My problem is, that every time when I use the first link to toggle the description on or off, also STUFF happens which is not supposed to be the case. How can I avoid STUFF from happening when clicking on the first link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first link does not need `remote: true`. Setting that causes [jquery_ujs](https://github.com/rails/jquery-ujs/wiki/Unobtrusive-scripting-support-for-jQuery) to try to submit the link automatically via ajax when you click it.  Removing `remote: true` should prevent the toggle link from triggering the `objects` action.

Separately, your `click` handler should either return `false` or call [`e.preventDefault()`](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/) to prevent the browser from trying to follow the link (basically you're telling the browser "ignore this click, I handled it"):

```
$(document).on "ready page:load", ->
  $("section.object").on "click", "#desc-link", (e) ->
    $("#object-desc").fadeToggle()
    e.preventDefault() // <-- prevents following the link
```