# How to implement link_to, AJAX, remote: true, respond_to without rendering new url Rails 6

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to implement adding upvote and downvotes to an app, submit the controller actions remotely using a button or link_to, and refresh a count section with AJAX.

Somehow upvoting or downvoting always redirects to a path of a member. When I use `head :no_content`, I can't submit the form aka `link_to`. Having some `respond_to do | f |...` also just renders the action URL.

Thus, `remote: true` is kind of not working, as I have another controller using `<%= form_for([entry, entry.review], remote: true, :authenticity_token => true) do |f| %>` and it works perfectly.

I have tried implementing [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46733619/how-do-i-implement-remote-true-functionality-without-link-to), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26808696/rails-4-rendering-a-partial-with-ajax-jquery-remote-true-and-respond-to), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39933196/rails-make-link-to-example-remote-true-bypass-respond-to-format), and [this](https://www.devwalks.com/lets-build-instagram-part-5-liking-larrys-legs-step-two/) tutorial and [this](https://medium.com/@albychen5/liking-unliking-w-ajax-and-acts-as-votable-gem-6ce440af9b16) but nothing seems to work.

I'm using the [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable). Everything works except the routing functionality with AJAX

```
# routes.rb
resources :entries do
  member do
    post 'upvote'
    post 'unupvote'
    post 'downvote'
    post 'undownvote'
  end
end
```

```
# entries_controller.rb
  def upvote
    @entry.liked_by current_user
  end

  def unupvote
    @entry.unliked_by current_user
  end

  def downvote
    @entry.disliked_by current_user
  end

  def undownvote
    @entry.undisliked_by current_user
  end
```

```
# entries/index.html.erb
...
  <%= button_to upvote_entry_path(entry.id), remote: true,
              class: "btn",
              id: "upvote-button-#{ entry.id }" do %>
    <i class="bi bi-hand-thumbs-up" style="color: #ababab;" id="upvote-<%= entry.id  %>"></i>
    <small id="upcount-<%= entry.id %>" >
      <%= render 'entries/upvote', entry: entry %>
    </small>
  <% end %>
...
```

```
# entries/_upvote.html.erb
<%= entry.get_upvotes.size %>
```

```
# entries/upvote.js.erb
$('#upvote-<%= entry.id %>').className('bi bi-hand-thumbs-up-fill');
$('#upvote-<%= entry.id %>').attr('href', '/entries/<%= entry.id %>/unupvote');
$('#upcount-<%= entry.id %>').html('<%=j render 'entries/upvote', entry: entry %>');
```

---

Edit, I have changed my `link_to` to `button_to`, changed the routes to `post`

Comment: What kind of error message do you see in your logs?
Another thing, I'm surprised to see upvote_entry_path. Should it not be entries_upvote_path?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if your `a` tag is inside other elements but you might want to consider using a `button_to` instead of a `link_to`.

Comment: I did that, and changed my routes to `post`, and I still get routing with `remote: true`

Comment: Did you also shut off `turbo-links` by adding `data-turbolinks="false"` in the parent element?

Comment: I just removed the whole `turbo-links` functionality. I've read on lots of forums that it brings a lot of complications [here](https://community.theforeman.org/t/is-it-time-to-remove-turbolinks/7679/2) and other [here](https://www.danielsellergren.com/how-to-remove-turbolinks-from-rails-6)

Comment: That shouldn't be necessary I think. The last resort I can come up with is to try to strip everything from your page, back to `application.html.erb` if necessary, and try to get one working `link_to` or `button_to` first

Answer (score 0):

So far the temporary solution, not probably recommended but still does the job programming practice, is hiding and unhiding certain elements on specific conditions.

Upon user interaction (e.g `onClick`), unhide and hide elements while updating values that resemble the controller update. Simply simulate a refresh and update the form paths/controller actions they point to.

This will mostly work better with boolean [check-box forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66277189/how-to-use-ajax-to-reload-a-section-of-page-unrelated-to-rails-controller-action/66316360#66316360), likes or dislikes where variables will only alternate between two instances at max. Hence you don't have to write much javascript to handle pseudo outputs.

But still, I'm sure there's a better method for example `WebSockets` through `Action Cable`. That can probably be overkill but the closest to realtime updates. `respond_to` just doesn't seem to work